# Is there a limit to how many data plots you can have on a highcharts graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am creating a highcharts linear graph that has about exactly 1652 plot values. Zero is included many times on the x axis, there are many negative x values, and just as many positive y values.

For some reason The graph will not plot when unless I remove some of the data though I cannot pinpoint  the exact amount

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Newer versions of highcharts have a turboThreshold option under plot options that places restrictions on data > 1000 plots. Look-up 'turboThreshold' in the docs for a better explanation.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area